# Logstash: Handling a large number of different files from S3

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, devops

I have S3 bucket with this folder structure. Every user can have own tools, and I can get Logstash `.conf` file for each one.

```
|-- user_1
    |-- workflow_1
        |--tool_1_output.txt
        |--tool_2_output.txt
|-- user_2
    |-- workflow_1
        |--tool_11_output.txt
        |--tool_22_output.txt
...
|-- user_1000
    |-- workflow_1
        |--tool_123_output.txt
        |--tool_234_output.txt
```

Idea is to use [Logstash Distributor pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#distributor-pattern), but I am still in doubt what is best approach for setup. Priorities are: keeping Logstash reliable and having single `.conf` for each tool. I came to 2 designs:

1. In `pipelines.yml` there are:

   - Distributor pipeline with rules and logic, responsible for sending files to appropriate pipeline.
   - Tools pipelines. Every tool need to have `pipeline.id` and `path.config`

This way `.config` for every tool is isolated and independent. My main concern is what would happen if I frequently update `pipelines.yml` with new tools pipelines and I need Logstash to run without a hiccup. Can this potentially be problem on a larger scale?

2. In `pipelines.yml` there are:

   - User pipelines with `pipeline.id` and `path.config`.

This way every user have own `.conf` file with all rules and parsing logic for every tool he use and `pipelines.yml` reloads only with new user. But this way tools doesn't have own `.conf` files.

I would appreciate any idea or approach, for this kind of problem.